# How to create a Key store?

Tags: android, apk, release, androidx, android-keystore

I want to release my android app but when I create apk release version file, my app has blocked protected error. I had created many many key stores with android studio and KeyStore Explorer but they didn't work.
What should I do? How should I create key store?

P.S: I don't want to use [this site](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/protectappeals)  . I want to create a key store that works.
Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0):

Select Build -> Generate Signed APK -> Choose bundle or APk -> Create New Keystore

[image]

Comment: It didn't work. I told that before. I have tried that and KeyStore Explorer

Comment: When I create apk file, no. But when I install that apk file android get Blocked protected error. I know this error because of the key store. I had one but that key store deleted accidentally.